# excel match value(get row) in two-dimensional array

Tags: arrays, excel, multidimensional-array, excel-formula

I have the following structure in my excel sheet.

```
          E           F           G        H        
      ---------   ---------    ------    -------      
 2 |  blah        sometext     atext      smth
 3 |  textval     accc
 4 |  test        avfr
 5 |  check       
 6 |  ertyui      
 7 |
```

Can you suggest a way using **EXCEL functions** (**not VBA**) of getting back the row of a matching string?

For example: given `test` I need to get back `4`, given `ertyui` `6`

I need:

- the lookup to be done in all the columns of this two-dimensional array and
- have the function in one cell only

Comment: Isn't this a two-dimensional array?  The row dimension and the column dimension?  If so, consider changing the question to make it easier for other people to find in case a satisfactory solution is provided.

Comment: updated (is that what you mean?)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With your search string in A1:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((E2:H6=A1)*ROW(E2:H6))
```

Obviously this will fail if there is *more than one* occurrence of the search string within the range. However, each of the values in the dataset you provide is unique, so I presume that this is not an issue.

Besides, if that *was* a possibility, you would need to clarify which of potentially several different row numbers should be the preferred return.

Regards

Comment: Your assumption is correct that's exactly what I wanted. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it!

Comment: Doesn't work for me.  Created similar example, and it returns zero.  Excel for Mac 2011.   Different implementation?

Comment: No experience of that version - sorry.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe with the string sought in say J1, in K1 (the output) something like:

```
 =SUM(K2:K100)
```

and in K2 copied down to say K100:

```
=IF(ISERROR(MATCH(J$1,E2:I2,0)),"",ROW())
```

Comment: ok this works but I need to have the function in one cell only

Answer (score 0):

Look up examples using `=MATCH()`

```
=match("test", E1:E7, 0)
```

This should return 4.  Then modify accordingly.

Better yet, place your condition in some other cell, say `A1` and then you could use:

```
=match($A$1, E$2:E$7, 0)-1
```

Place that formula in cell `E1` and drag across the columns and you'll have a match per each column.

Comment: this is not what I want E1:E7 is just the first column of the array

Comment: Can you be more specific or provide additional clarity in your examples?  You could copy that formula across the columns and concatenate the results?

Answer (score -1):

use this vb function it takes the table as argument and the of col variable and row variable ( the table inserted in the function contain the row of row values and col names , in other word the all table ) :

```
Public Function find_by_x_y(table_range As Range, row_val As Variant,col_val As Variant, error_finding_value As Variant) As Variant

Dim row_index_found As Integer
Dim col_index_found As Integer
row_index_found = 0
col_index_found = 0
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer

For i = 2 To table_range.Rows.Count
    If table_range.Cells(i, 1).Value = row_val Then
        row_index_found = i
    End If
Next i

For j = 2 To table_range.Columns.Count
    If table_range.Cells(1, j).Value = col_val Then
        col_index_found = j
    End If
Next j
'MsgBox (" i = " & row_index_found & " , j = " & col_index_found)
If col_index_found <> 0 And row_index_found <> 0 Then
    find_by_x_y = table_range.Cells(row_index_found, col_index_found).Value
    Exit Function
Else
    find_by_x_y = error_finding_value
    Exit Function
End If

End Function
```

Comment: Not only is this VBA code which the OP explicitly does not want, it also doesn't do what the OP wants.