# Finding location of value from multiple columns

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, lookup

I have a 4x4 table. All the values in the table are unique.

```
    A   B   C   D
1   a   b   c   d
2   e   f   g   h
3   i   j   k   l
4   m   n   o   p
```

How do i find the `address` of a particular value? I've tried `=CELL("address",MATCH(A1,A1:D4,0))` to find `a` but it returns an error value because `=MATCH(A1,A1:D4,0)` is an error value.

It seems `=match` only works on a single row/column.

Any solutions to this?

Comment: Quick question, should multiple coccurances be taken into consideration here?

Comment: Nope, all the values are unique.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way to do it (without an array formula, i.e. without hitting cntrl-enter), based on [this solution to locate a value in a 2D array](https://exceljet.net/formula/get-location-of-value-in-2d-array).

[image]

I won't repeat the excellent explanation of how it works it, in order to properly credit the author on his website.

> **EDIT:**  Based on @Chronocidal's excellent suggestions, here is the new and improved version for reference:

[image]

Comment: Great answer as well. Thanks for the reference!

Comment: You can also use `=ADDRESS(Row, Column)` instead of `=CELL("address",INDIRECT("R" & Row & "C" & Column, FALSE))`.  (Also, the `-ROW(data)+1` and `-COLUMN(data)+1` are to find the Row and Column *in the array*, and should probably be removed to find the Row and Column *in the worksheet*)

Comment: Excellent suggestion!  see above edits with credit for @Chronocidal :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use the following with distinct values

```
=CELL("ADDRESS",INDEX(A1:D4,SMALL(IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("a",A1:D4))),ROW(1:4),99^99),1),SMALL(IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("a",A1:D4))),COLUMN(A:D),99^99),1)))
```

Enter as an array formula with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>

Data:

[image: Data]

---

You could move what you are looking for into a separate cell rather than hard code into the formula, and wrap the whole thing in an IFERROR in case not found e.g.

[image: example2]

Search value in G1 and formula in F1.

```
=IFERROR(CELL("ADDRESS",INDEX(A1:D4,SMALL(IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(G1,A1:D4))),ROW(1:4),99^99),1),SMALL(IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH(G1,A1:D4))),COLUMN(A:D),99^99),1))),"")
```

---

This returns the row where found:

```
SMALL(IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("a",A1:D4))),ROW(1:4),99^99),1)
```

This returns the column where found:

```
SMALL(IF(NOT(ISERROR(SEARCH("a",A1:D4))),COLUMN(A:D),99^99),1)
```

And then you use these for the intersect on the range indexed with

```
INDEX(A1:D4,.......)
```

Comment: Can you explain the formula a little bit? :)

Comment: Awesome! The formula works! But agree with @Pierre44, do you mind explaining the formula a little? It seems fairly complicated :)

Comment: There is a nice explanation of this technique here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24949769/6241235 My example uses same approach but is expanded for intersect as neither row nor column is known, only the bounding area.

Answer (score 1):

This formula returns the address of a given value in a two-dimensional array.

```vb
=LET(
  array,           B2:E5,
  findvalues,      C7,

  arrayrows,       ROWS(array),
  arraycols,       COLUMNS(array),
  rowindex,        SEQUENCE(arrayrows*arraycols,,1,1/arraycols),
  colindex,        MOD(SEQUENCE(arrayrows*arraycols,,0),arraycols)+1,
  flatarray,       INDEX(array,rowindex,colindex),
  valueflatindex,  MATCH(findvalues,flatarray,0),
  valuerow,        ROUNDUP(valueflatindex/arraycols,0),
  valuecol,        MOD(valueflatindex-1,arraycols)+1,
  absvaluerow,     MIN(ROW(array))+valuerow-1,
  absvaluecol,     MIN(COLUMN(array))+valuecol-1,

  ADDRESS(absvaluerow,absvaluecol,1)
)
```

```
    A        B        C        D        E
1
2            a        b        c        d
3            e        f        g        h
4            i        j        k        l
5            m        n        o        p
6
7            find:    g
8            formula: $D$3
```

More precisely, this formula scans a given array row by row and returns the address of the first occurrence of a given value.

If your Excel version does not support the latest functions, such as *LET*, the formula should still work if you rewrite it so that it does not use the LET variables.

**Find Multiple Values**

This formula can also find multiple values and return the dynamic array of cell addresses. For this, update *findvalues* accordingly:

```
  array,           B2:E5,
  findvalues,      B8:B11,
```

```
    A        B        C        D        E
1
2            a        b        c        d
3            e        f        g        h
4            i        j        k        l
5            m        n        o        p
6
7            find:    formula:
8            a        $B$2
9            c        $D$2
10           j        $C$4
11           p        $E$5
```

Answer (score 0):

And a last one using VBA:

```
Function FINDaddress(VALUESEARCHED As String, ra As Range) As Variant

Dim A As Range

    Set A = ra.Find(What:=VALUESEARCHED, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

FINDaddress = A.Address

End Function
```

After that you only need to use the homemade function:

```
=FINDaddress("a",A1:D4)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a custom `Function` via VBA:

---

### `findIn(what, where)`

> **returns**  a "`A1`" styled `String` of a sought element (`what`) in a range/array (`where`).
>   If not contained inside the searched range, returns "`Not found`"

```
Private Function findIn(ByVal what As String, ByVal where As Range) As String

   Dim res As Range
   Set res = where.Find(what, LookIn:=xlValues)

   If Not res Is Nothing Then
     findIn = Col_Letter(res.Column) & res.Row 'returns A1 styled result
   Else
     findIn = "Not Found"
   End If

End Function

'col number to letter by brettdj
'(so.com)/questions/12796973/function-to-convert-column-number-to-letter/49577009)
Function Col_Letter(lngCol As Long) As String
    Dim vArr
    vArr = Split(Cells(1, lngCol).Address(True, False), "$")
    Col_Letter = vArr(0)
End Function
```

So if we were to test it, produces result as expected:

```
Private Sub test()
    Range("E1") = findIn("d", Range("A1:D4"))
End Sub
```

[image]

Or you can also use it as a Worksheet Function, if you place it inside a separate module (`Insert -> Module`)

[image]